# Select and append rows with null value (SQL/VBA)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Can someone help in coding a Access SQL statement/Query where I have a table with columns as shown with Ident No not primary

```
Ident_No-----Data1-----Data2-----Data3-----Data4-----Data5-----Data6

1----------------abc--------def---------null---------null--------null--------null

1----------------null--------null---------ghi----------jkl----------null--------null

1----------------null--------null---------null---------null--------mno--------pqr
```

Looking for result as shown below in the query result or a new table.

```
Ident_No-----Data1-----Data2-----Data3-----Data4-----Data5-----Data6

1----------------abc--------def---------ghi---------jkl--------mno--------pqr
```

Please Help Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `group by` and get the `MAX()` value for each column like

```
select `Ident_No`, max(`Data1`), max(`Data2`), 
        max(`Data3`), max(`Data4`), max(`Data5`), max(`Data6`)
from tbl9999
group by Ident_No
```

See live here http://rextester.com/CIHY78216

Comment: Thank you, found a solution based on your input